# Comparing Index At Object

Tags: objective-c, arrays, indexing, picker

I'm new to objective C and i'm stuck on my assigment.
I have searched questions but none seem to answer my specific needs, hope you guys can help! :)

I'm making a picker view with 2 components; one with the all the united states and one with their capitals.

Now when a button is pushed i'd like an 'if else statement' to check if the indexes of the two arrays match and if it does create an action.
Could somebody help me with the opening condition? Right now it gives me the 'expected expression' error.

```
if (_stateList objectAtIndex:[]== _capitalList objectAtIndex[]) {

    // Defining State & capitalnames by row
    NSInteger stateRow = [self.picker selectedRowInComponent:StatesList];
    NSInteger capitalRow = [self.picker selectedRowInComponent:CapitalsList];

    // Defining the Selected states and selected capital in the row
    NSString *selectedState = self.stateList[stateRow];
    NSString *selectedCapital = self.capitalList[capitalRow];

    // Giving a title to the alert message
    NSString *title = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"You selected %@ and %@", selectedState, selectedCapital];

    // Alert Message
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:@"Thats right, +1 for you!" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Great!" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];

    [alert addAction:action];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

    // Updating the scores
    _rightScore++;
    _rightAnswer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", _rightScore];
    _scoreTotal = _rightScore - _wrongScore;
    _scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %i", _scoreTotal];


} else {

    // Defining State & capitalnames by row
    NSInteger stateRow = [self.picker selectedRowInComponent:StatesList];
    NSInteger capitalRow = [self.picker selectedRowInComponent:CapitalsList];

    // Defining the Selected states and selected capital in the row
    NSString *selectedState = self.stateList[stateRow];
    NSString *selectedCapital = self.capitalList[capitalRow];

    // Giving a title to the alert message
    NSString *title = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"You have selected %@ and %@", selectedState, selectedCapital];

    // Alert Message
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:@"Thats not correct, -1 for you." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Let me try again!" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];

    [alert addAction:action];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

    // Updating the scores
    _wrongScore++;
    _wrongAnswer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", _wrongScore];
    _scoreTotal = _rightScore - _wrongScore;
    _scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %i", _scoreTotal];


}
```

Comment: If you want to compare objects at index `i`, you should use `[[_stateList objectAtIndex: i] isEqual: [_capitalList objectAtIndex: i]]`. If you want to compare whole arrays, you could do `[_stateList isEqualToArray: _capitalList]`.

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks so much, now i can move forward again! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning the selected rows to two variables `stateRow` and `capitalRow`. What you seem to be wanting to do is then compare these two variables to see if that have the same value, e.g. `if (stateRow == capitalRow) { ... } else { ... }`

HTH

Comment: I used Tsnorri's answer: [[_stateList objectAtIndex: i] isEqual: [_capitalList objectAtIndex: i]] and it worked perfectly, thanks for your input!